Finding the general convolution of probability function with hypergeometric PDFs.
I am trying to find the generalized convolution of this PDF distribution.
$$f(n, \sigma; v)= \frac{2^{\frac{3}{2}-\frac{n}{2}} \sigma ^{-n-1} v^\frac{n - 1}{2} K_{\frac{ n - 1}{2}}\left(\frac{v}{\sigma ^2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}$$
with the assumptions that $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, n \ge 1$ and $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}, \sigma > 0$, with the domain $v \ge 0$. I am trying to find the generalized convolution to determine the following sum:
$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
$$
where $X_i$ are all IID.
My current work has been to convert this system to its Laplace Transform equivalent (I have tried Fourier as well, but the Laplace transform works better). The Fourrier transform of the function looks like this complicated mess:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(f(n, \sigma; v)) =     \frac{\left(\frac{1}{\sigma ^4 t^2+1}\right)^{n/2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}+\frac{i \sqrt{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) \left(\left(\sigma ^4 t^2+1\right) \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{n+1}{2};-\frac{1}{2};-t^2 \sigma
   ^4\right)-\left((n+3) \sigma ^4 t^2+1\right) \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{n+1}{2};\frac{1}{2};-t^2 \sigma ^4\right)\right)}{\pi  n \sigma ^2 t \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}
\end{align}
And the Laplace Transform is in the shape of:
$$
\mathcal{L}(f(n, \sigma; v)) = \left(\sec \left(\frac{\pi  d}{2}\right) \left(\left(\sigma ^4 t^2-1\right)^{-d/2}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \, _2\tilde{F}_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{3-d}{2};\frac{1}{t^2 \sigma ^4}\right)}{\sigma ^2 t \Gamma
   \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)}\right)\right){}
$$
To find the convolution I would then need to generalized sum it would then look like:
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}(\mathcal{L}(f(n, \sigma; v))^n)
$$
Given the complicated nature of this equation, I used Mathematica to try to solve for this solution; however, even that is unable to derive the solution. Solutions are able to be find for finite $n$ and even $d$ numbers as the Laplace transforms simplified to:
$$
    \left\{\frac{1}{\sigma ^2 t+1},\frac{\sigma ^2 t+2}{2 \left(\sigma ^2 t+1\right)^2},\frac{3 \sigma ^4 t^2+9 \sigma ^2 t+8}{8 \left(\sigma ^2
   t+1\right)^3},\frac{5 \sigma ^6 t^3+20 \sigma ^4 t^2+29 \sigma ^2 t+16}{16 \left(\sigma ^2 t+1\right)^4}\right\}
$$
for $d = 2,4,6,8$. For the generalized $n$ value Mathematica was only able to compute generalized formula for $d = 2, 4$:
\begin{align}
    \left\{\frac{e^{-v} v^{n-1}}{\Gamma (n)},-2^{-n} n e^{-2 v} v^{n-1} \left(\, _1\tilde{F}_1(2 n;n+1;v)-2 \, _1\tilde{F}_1(2 n+1;n+1;v)\right) \right\}
\end{align}
Where $\, _m\tilde{F}_n$ represents the Hypergeometric m Fn Regularized (https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html).
Would anyone know how to find the generalized formula? I want to find this as I am trying to compute the ratio distribution of:
$$
\frac{w_i^2}{w_i^2 + \sum_{j = 1, j \neq i}^{d} w_j^2 + \sum_{j = 1, j \neq i}^{n}\left|w_i w_{a, j} + \sum_{k = 1}^{d - 1}w_{b, k}  w_{c, k}  \right|}
$$
$w_i^2$ and $\sum_{j = 1, j \neq i}^{d} w_j^2$, with the assumption that $w_i$ are Normal distributions which are IID, are obviously Chi-Sqaured distributions; however, $\sum_{j = 1}^{n}\left|\sum_{k = 1}^{d }w_{b, k}  w_{c, k}  \right|$ is the problem. The PDF $f(n, \sigma; v)$ represents in $\left|\sum_{k = 1}^{d }w_{b, k} w_{c, k} \right|$ and so the outer sum still needs to be computed.
I am trying to find the expected value of the above equation; however, due to the dependence on the numerator and the denominator (due to $w_i$), I am trying to use it to compute the Ratio Distribution and then compute the expected value from that (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution). To do this, given the dependence of the variables, I need to calculate the joint PDF of the variables.
(and no I do not want to use the Central Limit Theorem, unless absolutely necessary)

Please correct your indexes of summation. Who are $\ell, $k,a,b,c$?

$a,b,c$ don't truly matter; they are just meant to represent two independent random variables. I am unsure what the $l$ refers to, as I do not see one.

You have some $d_l$ and $n_l$ it seems to me. More interestingly, how do you prove that the integral of $f(n, 1, v)$ is one?  I am not able to do it from the integral representation of $K_{\nu}.$

Are numerical approximations to the convolved density of value, or are you only interested in an exact solution?

@LetacGérard I can't do it myself, but Mathematica seems sure it integrates to 1 for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \sigma > 0$

@LetacGérard I agree with Martin Modrak 's comment. I am unable to compute the integral of $\int_{0}^{\infinity} f(n, \sigma; v) dv = 1$ manually but Mathematica is able to demonstrate that for all $n, \sigma$ it is the case:
Integrate[(2^(3/2 - n/2)*v^((-1 + n)/2)*\[Sigma]^(-1 - n)*     BesselK[(-1 + n)/2, v/\[Sigma]^2])/(Sqrt[Pi]*Gamma[n/2]), {v,    0, \[Infinity]},   Assumptions -> {\[Sigma] > 0, n \[Element] PositiveIntegers}]

@MartinModrák Yes, I would like to find the exact solution for this distribution.

Instead of the integral representation, one could use the representation of $K_{(n-1)/2}$ by a simple finite sum {a  treatise of the Theory of Bessel Functions, G.N. Watson, page 80 formulas 12 and 15) for checking that $f(n,1,t)$ is a probablity. This is enough for your purpose and frustrating since this probably true when $n$ is replaced bya continuous parameter
